# How to bind dynamic reference based on configuration?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, felix-dependency-manager

I have following consumer component that uses a reference service called `sender`,

```
    @Component(configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE, configurationPid = DATA_SYNC_CONFIG)
    public class DataSynchronizer {

        @Reference
        private TelemetrySender sender;

        //calls some methods of sender
}
```

And this works fine as long as there is one implementation for interface `TelementrySender`

But if there are two implementations for that interface, and if I want to select which implementation to bind based on configuration property , what is the correct way to do it? According to my understanding and findings following method is tried.

included a bind method to my component as follows.

```
   @Component(configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE, configurationPid = DATA_SYNC_CONFIG)
    public class DataSynchronizer {

        private TelemetrySender sender;

       @Reference
        void setSender(TelemetrySender telemetrySender ) {
            // read configuration and set only correct implementation 
           this.sender= telemetrySender ;
         }

        //calls some methods of sender
}
```

one of my `TelemetrySender` implementation is as follows,

```
@Component(configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE, configurationPid = HTTP_TELEMETRY_SENDER_CONFIG,property={ "service=http" })
 public class HttpConnector implements TelemetrySender {
}
```

My problem is how to select correct `TelemntrySender` inside `setSender` method? Or if I'm using wrong approach please correct me. I referred [this article](http://blog.vogella.com/2016/06/21/getting-started-with-osgi-declarative-services/)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use an attribute in the config `sender.target=<search filter>`.
See [OSGi compendium 112.6.2.1](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#d0e40380).

So if the service you want to bind has the property sendername=my then you could set:

```
sender.target=(sendername=my)
```